# How to load sequelize models in a NextJS 13 app

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, next.js13, node-sqlite3

I'm using nextJS 13 to create my web app. I want to use sequelize to query my database.

I have a file that initialize sequelize and the models, but when I start the app, it can't find the models (the "database/models" folder does not exist in the compiled ".next" folder) :

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

import fs from 'node:fs';
import path from 'node:path';

const models: { [key: string]: any } = {};

const modelsDir = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'database', 'models');

// Create a sqlite DB (using sequelize)

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: './db.sqlite3',
    logging: (msg: any) => console.log(msg),
});

// Create the models 

fs.readdirSync(modelsDir)
    .filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'))
    .forEach(async file => {
        const modelPath = path.join(modelsDir, file);
        const { default: model } = await import(modelPath);
        models[model.name] = new model(sequelize, DataTypes);
    });

Object.keys(models).forEach(modelName => {
    if (models[modelName].associate) {
        models[modelName].associate(models);
    }
});

export { sequelize, models };
```

And here is a sample of my model :

```
import { CreationOptional, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '@/lib/database';

class Shift extends Model<InferAttributes<Shift>, InferCreationAttributes<Shift>> {
    declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
    declare userId: string;
    ...
}

Shift.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    ...
}, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'shifts',
});

export default Shift;
```

TO initialize the connection I added this in the global `layout.tsx` (not so sure when to place this) :

```
try {
        console.log('Initializing database');
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await sequelize.sync();


        console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
    }
    catch (err) {
        return console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    }
```

FYI, I had to [enable an experimental feature to use sequelize in the app](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7509#issuecomment-1529600682)

Am I doing something wrong here ? Am I missing something ? Why the models are not compiled to the `.next` folder